# How to set featureCompatibilityVersion without access to Mongo shell in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to install MongoDB 3.2 on my local machine, running Ubuntu 16.10.

During install, no errors; then, when I run `mongod`, I get the following errors:

`Cannot start mongod when the featureCompatibilityVersion is higher than 3.2. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-feature-compatibility.`

`Fatal Assertion 40352`

However, when I go to that link in MongoDB's documentation, the only way it shows to set the feature compatibility is through the `mongo` shell. Yet I can't even access this, as I mentioned earlier and is shown in the terminal output below.

I had previously installed MongoDB 3.4, but I need to have 3.2, because that's the latest version compatible with mLab, which I will be using when moving to production.

So first I tried downgrading it, and I had the same problem as here. Then I tried uninstalling 3.4 completely (following their uninstall instructions) and installing 3.2. Then I got the same error.

Here is the full terminal output:

```
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3465 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=fluidlan
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-10T09:42:10.134+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-02-10T09:42:10.160+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-02-10T09:42:10.160+0530 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-02-10T09:42:10.160+0530 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2017-02-10T09:42:10.160+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-02-10T09:42:10.955+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-02-10T09:42:10.955+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-02-10T09:42:10.955+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-02-10T09:42:10.955+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-02-10T09:42:10.958+0530 F INDEX    [initandlisten] Cannot start mongod when the featureCompatibilityVersion is higher than 3.2. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-feature-compatibility.
2017-02-10T09:42:10.958+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40352
2017-02-10T09:42:10.959+0530 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Perhaps there are still files I didn't fully delete during the uninstall process? I did the following to uninstall (as per their installation guide):

`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

`sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb`

`sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`

But perhaps that didn't fully purge everything?

In any regard, how can I set feature compatibility without access to the `mongo` shell?

Thank you.

P.S. I've been following the instructions for Ubuntu 16.04, because there aren't any for 16.10 yet. Could that be the source of the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to delete files from `/var/lib/mongodb` but according to your log file the data files are in `/data/db`.

Try removing files from the `/data/db/` to solve the issue:

`sudo rm -rf /data/db*`

Comment: So after deleting everything fro `/data/db/` and reinstalling, I'm now getting errors regarding permissions: `exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
`

Comment: Now I've changed permissions for that directory and things seem to be working fine! Thanks.